# How do I stop my jacket mesh from flinging once on a hook?

Tags: mesh

I'm still pretty new to blender. Here's the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZt-CWT6_eLO8zi1WaaBDYkYBu4i0L_z/view?usp=sharing

[image: im trying to make a mesh fall on a hook but it ends up doing this instead]

Comment: one reason for sure is the really bad topology of the arms and the collar. Next reason is the size - increase it by 10 and apply and it will look better. Maybe increase it even by 100. Also you should check "self collisition". As solidify modifier + subdivision after the cloth modifier improves it too.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Also, instead of using a collision object to hang it, why don't you simply create a pin group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris says, fix the topology:

[image]

Create a vertex group where the cloth is supposed to hang:

[image]

Choose this group as *Pin Group*, enable *Object Collisions* and *Self-Collisions*, increase the collisions *Quality*:

[image]

Maybe add a *Solidify* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]